# How to get a dotted rule below every subsection title in scrartcl?

Tags: koma-script, titles, rules, subsection

I am currently doing the following in order to obtain a rule below each section title in a KOMA Article.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

% RULE BELOW SECTION TITLES

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
\ifstr{#1}{section}{%
    \parbox[t]{\linewidth}{%
      \raggedsection\@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}\par%
      \kern-1.00\ht\strutbox\rule{\linewidth}{.8pt}%
    }%
  }{%
    \@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}}% 
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Whatever}

\subsection{Whatever else}

\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image]

I have tried to modify this approach to obtain a dotted rule below every subsection title, but I haven’t succeeded.

**Could you please help me generate a dotted rule below every subsection title?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use package `dashrule`:

```latex
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{dashrule}

% RULE BELOW SECTION TITLES

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
\Ifstr{#1}{section}{%
    \parbox[t]{\linewidth}{%
      \raggedsection\@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}\par%
      \rule[1.5ex]{\linewidth}{.8pt}%
    }%
  }{%
    \Ifstr{#1}{subsection}{%
    \parbox[t]{\linewidth}{%
    \raggedsection\@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}\par
    \hdashrule[1.5ex]{\linewidth}{.8pt}{.8pt}}}%
    {\@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}\par}%%
    }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Whatever}

\subsection{Whatever else}

\end{document}
```

I hope that is what you asked for:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately, I want a normal rule below the section title, and dotted rules below subsection titles. Your answer provides a dotted rule below section titles. Therefore, I cannot accept this answer.

Comment: @cabohah you're right. I misread it...

Comment: @cabohah Thank you for your comments. What do you mean by “will you add the second case?”?

Comment: @cabohah Changing `\ifstr` for `\Ifstr` generates an error and fails to compile the document.

Comment: @Hector In this case your TeX distribution is very, very outdated. As already said: `\ifstr` is deprecated for more than three years.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer. My TeX distribution is not outdated, as I am using Overleaf with the most up-to-date settings available. There are no subsubsections in my document, so I am not bothered about that.

Comment: @Hector `\Ifstr` is available from KOMA-Script 2019/12/23 v3.28. At the same time `\ifstr` became deprecated. So if `\Ifstr` is not defined but `\ifstr` is, you *are* using an outdated distribution. Using Overleaf does not automatically mean, that you are using an up-to-date TeX installation. For example old projects AFAIK are not automatically use new installed TeX Live releases.

Comment: @cabohah, was not clear from the OP's question. But i added the necessary condition to print the lines only below `subsection`.

Comment: @Hector I also edited the code of your rule, so that both rules are raised by the same dimen. Of course, you can adjust it.

Comment: Unfortunately, your current solution does not compile in a new Overleaf document using Live Tex 2023. It gives a Runaway argument? error.

Comment: Just a typo, deleted a brace. Corrected

Comment: Thank you. Your solution works. I have therefore accepted it.

Comment: @Hectro Does this mean that changing `\ifstr` to `\Ifstr` does not result in an error message, so your earlier comment was incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a suggestion similar to @lukeflo's, but using LaTeX3's `\str_case:nn` instead of KOMA-Script's `\ifstr` (deprecated) or `\Ifstr`:

```latex
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{dashrule}

%\usepackage{expl3}% should not be needed any longer, but if you are
                  % using a very old LaTeX installation, you can activate it

% RULE BELOW SECTION TITLES

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
    {
      { section }
        {
          \parbox[t]{\linewidth}{
            \raggedsection\@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}\par
            \kern-1.00\ht\strutbox\rule{\linewidth}{.8pt}
          }
        }
      { subsection }
        {
          \parbox[t]{\linewidth}{
            \raggedsection\@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}\par
            \hdashrule[2ex]{\linewidth}{.8pt}{.8pt}
          }
        }
    }
    {
      \@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}
    }
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Example of section}
\blindtext

\subsection{Example of subsection}
\blindtext

\subsubsection{Example of subsubsection}
\blindtext

\paragraph{Example of paragraph}
\blindtext

\subparagraph{Example of subparagraph}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

See [The LaTeX3 Interfaces](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf) for more information about LaTeX3 and functions like `\str_case:nn`.

Comment: Personally I would prefer your version, since LaTeX3 seems simply more straightforward in most cases! +1

Comment: @lukeflo Yes, LaTeX3 offers nice features. But in this case it is not really LaTeX3 code, but only using one LaTeX3 feature. Real LaTeX3 code should IMHO also replace, e.g., `\parbox` or at least `\hskip`. So IMHO it is a quite ugly mixture. However this kind it is easier to understand for l3 beginners.

Comment: But in many cases its still a mixture of latex2e and latex3 source code, since most packages aren't relying heavily on latex3 up-do-date. At the moment I'm converting much of my personal stuff to latex3, but AFAIK sometimes there are features which are not yet fully implemented in latex3. But thats way off-topic... ;)